# apache storm reliablity timeout configuration

Tags: apache-storm

I have a nodejs->kafka>storm->Mongo deployed in Linux Ubuntu. Everything is normal originally. Then I changed the method in storm worker which makes storm worker process message very slow, around 1 minute per message, I notice the message is sent again and again from storm. I revert back to original method, everything is fine. (original method process time is 90ms per message).

I guess this is Storm reliability come into player. When message is not acknowledged, or time out, it sends message again.

If my guess is right, how to configure this timeout?

If my guess is wrong, why same message is sent twice or three times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the timeout via configuration parameter `Config.TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS`. See https://storm.apache.org/javadoc/apidocs/backtype/storm/Config.html#TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS

The default value is 30 seconds, see `defaults.yaml` here: https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml

```
# maximum amount of time a message has to complete before it's considered failed
topology.message.timeout.secs: 30
```

When a tuple fails, it should show up in Storm UI and should be logged, too (maybe you need to adjust log level). So you can double check if a tuple times out or not.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matthias. What about the default value of this configuration parameter( TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS)? I did not set it at all since I do not know this parameter at all.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax For some reason despite setting this field and despite being displayed in the UI : topology.enable.message.timeouts = false, application is still timing out. I am using 0.10.0. Would you happen to know anything about this issue?

Comment: Not sure. As a work around, just set the timeout to `Long.MAX_VALUE` ;)

Comment: if you are going to use Long.MAX_VALUE why use the reliability API.